# Sorting and ranking in apache spark scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, ranking, bigdata

I wanted to do ranking in spark, as follows:

**Input:**

```
5.6
5.6
5.6
6.2
8.1
5.5
5.5
```

**Ranks:**

```
1
1
1
2
3
0
0
0
```

**Output:**

```
Rank Input 
0     5.5
0     5.5
1     5.6
1     5.6
1     5.6
2     6.2
3     8.1
```

I wanted to know how I can sort these in spark and also get the same ranking as listed above. The requirements are:

1. ranking starts with 0 not 1
2. this is a sample case for millions of records and one partition may be very large - I appreciate recommendation on how to rank using an internal sorting method

I wanted to do this in scala. Can someone help me write code for this?

Comment: How many different scores do you expect? thousands, millions?

Comment: Are ranks passed in as well or are you expecting the rank to be derived from the sort of the input? The comment about applying the rank to the index makes this unclear to me

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto so there are multiple cases, rank all or just top 10 or 20. I need to support all cases. so answer is all millions.

Comment: If millions then you must use a `sortBy` :(

Comment: @Bryce sorry. Didn't meant to say rank to index, I was meant to say, the input valeus should be sorted on ranks not by order index like in our case, it can be 0,1,2 ...7. Rather 0,0. Have to support the corner case when two inputs are redundant occur moire than once will get same ranking.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto : oh bad. lets say if not millions and just by 10 or 20 or K <1000. What would you recommend to do it optimally. As we do paging, i guess top 10 or 20 is just displayed.

Comment: sorry but either case will require you to `sort`, the thing is that is the number of groups is small you could do a collect...

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto oh ok. One thing unclear is does the default sorting in spark ranks the same way as above or it output index as 1,2,3 so on. I thought to zip and get index. I am not familiar on how sorting in spark works.Any link the you recommend to read to get more detail on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect just **some** ranks you could first get all `distinct` values, collect them as a `List` and transform them into a `BroadCast`. Below, I show a dirty example, notice that it isn't guaranteed that the output will be sorted (there might probably be better approaches, but this is the first thing that comes to my mind):

```
// Case 1. k is small (fits in the driver and nodes)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,1,44,4,1,33,44,1,2))
val distincts = rdd.distinct.collect.sortBy(x => x)
val broadcast = sc.broadcast(distincts)

val sdd = rdd.map{
  case i: Int => (broadcast.value.asInstanceOf[Array[Int]].indexOf(i), i)
}

sdd.collect()

// Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,1), (0,1), (4,44), (2,4), (0,1), (3,33), (4,44), (0,1), (1,2))
```

In the second approach I sort using Spark's functionality, in the [RDD's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) you could find how `zipWithIndex` and `keyBy` work.

```
//case 2. k is big, distinct values don't fit in the Driver.
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(1,1,44,4,1,33,44,1,2))
val distincts = rdd.distinct.sortBy(x => x).zipWithIndex
rdd.keyBy(x => x)
  .join(distincts.keyBy(_._1))
  .map{
    case (value: Int, (v1: Int, (v2: Int, index: Long))) => (index, value)
  }.collect()

//res15: Array[(Long, Int)] = Array((3,33), (2,4), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (0,1), (4,44), (4,44), (1,2))
```

By the way, I use `collect` just for visualization purposes, in a real app you shouldn't use it unless you are sure it fits in the driver's memory.

Comment: thank you so much. it provides the expected results. Since I am more concerned on the performance, I wanted to understand the internals on how the sorting occurs. In the case where if one key with 100k records, the partition would be huge, so wondering is sortby is the only option or any suggestion on using a library. I use the same in python using Numpy and it does sorting really well. Looking something similar.

Comment: The problem is that if k is huge the way how sorts is executed by spark is by moving several values among partitions, which is really inefficient; but i will add it as case 2.

Comment: Currently i am getting the results in a unsorted way. For the case 2, can I get it in a sorted format based on the rank. like (0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(1,2), ....etc?

Comment: Well as I told you, it isn't guaranteed that the result is sorted, and more after you use a collect, but I guarantee that every element has its own rank. Let me tell you something more, you look very worried about positions of records on `RDD`s, and normally when you work with Spark that shouldn't be a problem (there are special cases like windows, etc). If you aren't satisfied with the answer, feel free to unmark it.

Comment: i am satisfied with the answer. I am just trying to understand the case here. thank you for the explanation. Appreciate it